# How to limit Java's stack size on a per-thread basis?

Tags: java, stack, java-threads, stack-size

The title asks it all, really. If setting the stack size of an individual thread directly in the JVM isn't possible, are there any alternatives?

Comment: @AndyTurner "any alternatives" as in ways to simulate a stack size cap such as using tools or monitoring the stack and using `Thread.stop` when it gets too large... Preferably not that because `Thread.stop` is deprecated. Apologies if you got mentioned twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread-java.lang.ThreadGroup-java.lang.Runnable-java.lang.String-long-):

> ```
> public Thread(ThreadGroup group,
>               Runnable target,
>               String name,
>               long stackSize)
> ```
>
> ...
>
> stackSize - the desired stack size for the new thread, or zero to
>   indicate that this parameter is to be ignored.

As pointed out by [Jacob G.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7294647/jacob-g), it says in the same documentation (with original emphasis):

> **On some platforms, the value of the `stackSize` parameter may have no effect whatsoever.**

Comment: Small note from the linked documentation: "On some platforms, the value of the stackSize parameter may have no effect whatsoever."